# Como llenar un DataGridView desde un DataTable creada desde MySql con una columna tipo checkbox en C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, datatables, datagrid

Quiero llenar un datagridview con una consulta a esta tabla [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con la que lleno un datatable de esta forma:

```
public DataTable VistaTabla()
    {
        instruccion = "select * from pedido";
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(instruccion, conexion());
        DataTable consulta = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(consulta);
        return consulta;

    }
```

y el datagridview lo lleno asi

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = obje.VistaTabla();
```

La cuestion aqui es que quiero que el campo que tengo como "pagada" quiero que en el datagridview se muestre como un checkbox ( de ser necesario puedo cambiar el tipo de campo) , alguien que me pueda apoyar en como mostrarlo de esta forma ( Si es 'N' que el checkbox esta desmarcado y si es 'S' que este marcado)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta claro que un `char(1)` no es un `boolean` para que pueda se representado como checkbox

podrias definirlo en la consulta

```
 string instruccion = @"select campo1, 
                            campo2, 
                            campo3 = CASE 
                                        WHEN campo3 = 'S' THEN yes 
                                        ELSE false 
                                     END
                    from pedido";
```

si defines los campos podras convertir el S/N en un valor boolean para usarlo en el grid como checkbox

[CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014)

Ademas recomendaria que definas las columnas en diseños usando la propiedad "DataPropertyName" para indicar cada columna del grid con que campo de la tabla mapea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Definiendo las columnas tendras un mayor control como estas se representan pudiendo definir que sea del tipo `DataGridViewCheckBoxColum`

Comment: Muchas gracias, entiendo la logica de esto, pero soy algo nuevo y no se como definir el datapropertyname de mis columnas, pues si lo intento asi nada mas solo me da la opcion de "ninguno", y si defino las columnas del datagridview  e indico el datasource como lo hago normalmente lo que hace es crearme columnas adelante de las declaradas y las que ya tengo definidas simplemente las ignora , me podrias apoyar con este problema por favor? gracias de antemano

Comment: puede localizar la opcion de la imagen?, es alli donde agregas las columnas en tiempo de diseño, si seleccinas la columna tendra la propiedades donde asignar esta que menciono

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba tratando de pickear la opcion desde el combo que te sale en el datapropertyname pero no habia notado que puedes escribir directamente ahi , solo cambie el true y false de la consulta con el case por 0 y 1 por que el sql no me lo reconocia